# Varnish 4.0 multiple matches

Tags: regex, varnish, vcl

I need to invalidate cache in Varnish for multiple specific values of one parameter simultaneously. Now the code makes calls following this pattern:

```
varnish_host/path?.*parameter=1
varnish_host/path?.*parameter=2
varnish_host/path?.*parameter=3
varnish_host/path?.*parameter=4
```

And following a documentation of Varnish 2.0 found here https://kly.no/varnish/regex.txt I found this rule for multiple matching

```
Multiple matches
    req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|css|js)$"
    True if req.url ends with either "jpg", "jpeg", "css" or "js".
```

So I changed my code to adapt it in the following way

```
varnish_host/path?.*parameter=(1|2|3|4)$
```

But it does not clean the cache as expected, even if it returns a status 200.

Is there in Varnish 4.0 a way to do this multiple match in a parameter? If so, is there a limit in the number of variations that we should have into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varnish doesn't offer an *out-of-the-box* HTTP-based invalidation mechanism.

What you can do is [issue *bans* using `varnishadm`](http://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/varnish-cli.html#ban-field-operator-arg-field-oper-arg). This will allow you to setup regex patterns that match multiple objects.

### Varnishadm ban example

Here's such an example, where we will invalidate each *PNG* file in the cache for the *example.com* hostname:

```
varnishadm ban req.http.host == example.com '&&' req.url '~' '\\.png$'
```

### HTTP-based banning & purging

`varnishadm` works fine, but isn't that easy to integrate into your logic. If you want to invalidate objects from the cache via *purge* or *ban*, you need to write some VCL.

Here's a VCL snippet that will facilitate *HTTP-based invalidation*:

```
vcl 4.0;

acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "192.168.55.0"/24;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
            return(synth(405, "Not allowed."));
        }
        if (!req.http.ban-url) {
            return(purge);
        }
        ban("obj.http.x-host == " + req.http.host + " && obj.http.x-url ~ " + req.http.ban-url);
        return(synth(200, "Ban added"));
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.http.x-url = bereq.url;
    set beresp.http.x-host = bereq.http.host;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    unset resp.http.x-url;
    unset resp.http.x-host;
}
```

> Important: you need to adjust the values of the *ACL*, which will prohibit unauthorized access to the invalidation interface. You can use *IP addresses*, *IP ranges*, and *hostnames* to limit access.

Here's how we perform the same *PNG* invalidation via HTTP:

```
curl -XPURGE -H"ban-url: '\.png$'" http://example.com/
```

You can also just invalidate a single URL:

```
curl -XPURGE http://example.com/my-page
```

Because the example above doesn't contain an `ban-url` request header, only the exact URL is invalidated, instead of a pattern begin matched.